# laravel $title is undefined Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $title }} with {{ $title ?? '' }}

Tags: php, laravel

[`$title is undefined Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $title }} with {{ $title ?? '' }}`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIf0t.png)

index.blade.php is working

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

  {{ $title }}
  
@endsection
```

but the about and service not working with the same code .
in my PageController.php

```
    public function index(){
        $title = 'welcome hiii';
        return view('pages.index')->with('title', $title);
    }

    public function about(){
        $title = 'welcome hiiissssssss';
        return view('pages.about')->with('title', $title);
    }

    public function services(){
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'services'
        );
        return view('pages.services')->with($data);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... the error is telling you how to avoid the error ... have you done their suggestion?

Comment: How did you define the route. Can we see your route code?

Comment: on which page it gives you `$title` error ?

Comment: try to be clear in your question and put full related data and where are the error details? where is your route details?

Answer (score 0):

Title will only be a variable if you [flash the data to the session](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) like making a redirect.

Instead you can use

```php
return view('pages.services', compact('title'));
```

Or

```php
return view('pages.services', ['title' => '...']);
```

Comment: the problem is not on the controller.

Comment: @STA so where is it?